# How to create a binary variable based on changes in another column?

Tags: r

I'm attempting to count the number of times the column shore changes from West to East and vice versa for each ID. Here is a subset of my dataframe

```
structure(list(ID = c(30767L, 30767L, 30767L, 30767L, 30767L, 
30767L, 30767L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 
30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 
30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 
30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 30759L, 
30759L, 30759L, 30759L), shore = c("West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"East", "West", "East", "East", "West", "West", "West", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "West", "East", "West", 
"West", "West", "West", "West", "East", "East", "East", "East", 
"East", "East", "East", "East")), row.names = c(NA, -40L), groups = structure(list(
    ID = c(30759L, 30767L), .rows = list(8:40, 1:7)), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Basically what I am looking to do first is identify no changes as - a West-East movement as 0 and an East-West movement as 1.. See example below.

```
      ID Shore Direction
1  30759  West         -
2  30759  West         -
3  30759  West         -
4  30759  East         0
5  30759  West         1
6  30759  East         0
7  30759  East         -
8  30759  West         1
9  30759  West         -
10 30759  West         -
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by `ID` and then use `case_when` with `lag` to compute the variable.

```
library(dplyr)

DF %>%
  group_by(ID) %>%
  mutate(dir = case_when(
    shore == "West" & lag(shore) == "East" ~ 1L,
    shore == "East" & lag(shore) == "West" ~ 0L,
    TRUE ~ NA_integer_)) %>%
  ungroup
```

Comment: I don't think this is quite what I'm looking for, see edited post.

Comment: Have revised it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way, using `dplyr`:

```
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(prev = lag(shore),
                direction = dplyr::case_when(shore == "West" & prev == "East" ~ 1,
                                             shore == "East" & prev == "West" ~ 0,
                                             TRUE ~ NA_real_))
```

The `lag()` function gives the previous entry of (in this case) the `shore` column. Then I've added a direction column which is `1` when the direction changes from East to West, `0` when the direction changes from West to East, and `NA` otherwise. You could then drop the `prev` column.